# Escaping commands in ssh connection via for loop

Tags: bash, ssh

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in ontwikkelkaart
do
    echo "***";
    echo ${x};

    ssh ${x}@localhost "
        find ~/public_html/wp-content/themes/ -type f -name "*.webp" | awk '{ gsub(".webp$", "") ; print $0 }' | xargs -i sh -c 'if [ ! -f "{}" ]; then echo {}.webp; fi' \;
    "
done
```

I have the above script that connects to a server via SSH, it checks wether there are webp files with no jpg/png as source file; and echo's rm "filename".

The command:

```
find ~/public_html/wp-content/themes/ -type f -name "*.webp" | awk '{ gsub(".webp$", "") ; print $0 }' | xargs -i sh -c 'if [ ! -f "{}" ]; then echo {}.webp; fi' \;
```

Works when i run it on the command line of the server (via SSH), but when i try to do it in the for loop, it does not work because of the "".

Can someone (try to) explain why the above code does not work?

Comment: better to do that is create an script and do ssh user@servername bash < your_local_script.bash

Comment: Or scp the file and run that on the target server with the ssh command.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a heredoc :

```
ssh -q -T ${x}@localhost 2> /dev/null <<'EOF'
find ~/public_html/wp-content/themes/ -type f -name "*.webp" | awk '{ gsub(".webp$", "") ; print $0 }' | xargs -i sh -c 'if [ ! -f "{}" ]; then echo {}.webp; fi' \;
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i run the above i get the following error:

`images.sh: line 13: warning: here-document at line 7 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
images.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @user2739456 Is the EOF line indented? **It has to be at the beginning of the line**

Comment: I'd suggest qutoing the first `'EOF'` or variables such as `$0` will get expanded inside the here-doc.